# Android Widget Wrong Size

Tags: java, android, android-widget, widget

I have an Android widget. I would like it to be 4 cells width and 2 cells height. Right now the size of the widget is 4 by 4 (for some reason). And the strange thing is that the content of the widget, i.e. the frame (according to [this definition](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html)) is of small size.
So, most of the home screen is blank, but I cannot reposition the widget (seems that it takes all 4 by 4 cells on my home screen).
Here is the code of my widget-provider layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_demo" 
    android:minHeight="110dp" 
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000" 
    >
</appwidget-provider>
```

Here is the widget layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="110dp"    
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="1sp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widgetTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some_text"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30dp" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/widget_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="some_text" 
        android:textSize="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What is the problem? Why does it take 4 by 4 instead of 4 by 2?

Comment: have you tried to change your `LinearLayout` from `android:layout_height="110dp"` to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> App Widget layouts should be flexible, resizing to fit their parent container

So, change your LinearLayout

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="110dp"
```

to match parent size

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```